# How to optimize typescript nested for loop from O(n^2) to O(n) or similar?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, algorithm, ionic-framework

I have two arrays of objects namely `arr1` and `arr2` assuming the length of both are equal. Both have `{id: 'some random id', ...}` inner structure. I want to iterate through each object in `arr1` and add a parameter `checked=false` if `id` of that object didn't belong to `arr2` else add a `checked=true`.

Here is my present code:

```
for (const i of arr1) {
      i.checked = false;
      for (const j of arr2) {
        if (i.id === j.id) {
          i.checked = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

How do I optimize it? Any suggestions lesser than O(n^2) is appreciated.

Comment: Build an "index" object of arr2 where the keys are ids and the values are arr2's cell, so you can quickly look up the id in the arr2 index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Set, they have O(1) access making your loop O(n)

```
const idSet = new Set(arr2.map(i => i.id))

for (const i of arr1) {
      i.checked = idSet.has(i.id);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` to prepare IDs from the second array, and then use `Set.prototype.has` which has O(1) operation.

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]
const arr2 = [{id: 2}, {id: 5}, {id: 4}, {id: 6}]

const ids = new Set(arr2.map(({ id }) => id))

for (const item of arr1) {
  item.checked = ids.has(item.id)
}

console.log(arr1)

/* Result
[
  { id: 1, checked: false },
  { id: 2, checked: true },
  { id: 3, checked: false },
  { id: 4, checked: true }
]
*/
```

Quick benchmark:

```sh
Running "Array check (1000 elements)" suite...
Progress: 100%

  Set.has:
    15 671 ops/s, ±0.38%   | fastest

  two loops:
    543 ops/s, ±0.48%      | slowest, 96.54% slower

Finished 2 cases!
  Fastest: Set.has
  Slowest: two loops
```